# Mixed data types in one column (int and decimal): separate or get together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, sqldatatypes

In my Rails app (with PostgreSQL) I'm importing some `metrics` from Google Analytics:

1. Visitors - `int`
2. Goal 1 Completions - `int`
3. Goal 2 Completions - `int`
4. Goal N Completions - `int`
5. Transactions Amount - `int`
6. Transactions Revenue - `decimal`

Here's the table with data, if all of them were `int`:

`id` - `int`
`date` - `date`
`metric_id` - `int`
`metric_amount` - `int`

But Transactions Revenue is `decimal`, so I have 2 options.

Option 1. Make all of them decimal

`id` - `int`
`date` - `date`
`metric_id` - `int`
`metric_amount` - `decimal`

Option 2. Create additional nullable column for Revenue

`id` - `int`
`date` - `date`
`metric_id` - `int`
`metric_amount` - `int`
`metric_revenue` - `decimal`

Which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to have a separate column for each and every attribute of your metrics model.

Comment: For that you need a separate table: `Completions`, with a `belongs_to` relationship with your `metrics` model.

Comment: Actually, it's not only about Goal Completions. I'm making an Engine to use it with apps of my clients. Some of them need to import just Goals, some eCommerce and some Social stuff without Goals from GA. I don't know which metrics will be used in next project, so I try to make structure max flexible and define metric types inside App, not inside Engine.

Comment: so you need an even more flexible yet complex db modeling than a single table.

Comment: This is how I see it at the moment: [screen](http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/1826/w8y.png)